# Loading another html document within a div?- Advice?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a site where there will be four tiles on the front page. When a tile is selected, I want the content to pop up in like a window that will be a bit transparent so you can see the main page behind it.

I've successfully coded just that, getting the link to bring up another div that is otherwise hidden and I've even gotten it to load another html document. I accomplished this with XMLHttpRequest();. My question is, is there a more efficient way to do this? I know I've done something similar in PHP before in school and when I google, I do see that being a way to do it, but I'm also seeing jQuery and AJAX being mentioned. My overall goal is to get it to where if I want to update the CSS of the screens, that I only have to do that for the main page, and it affects the content pop-ups.

I hope I explained this well enough. Thank you for any advice!

Comment: see if this helps: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: you don't need to use four pages, you can just put hidden content in the div. your page will take slightly longer to "come up", but the tile navigation will then be instant, so over-all, time is saved if the page is used. it's also much easier for one person without a CMS to manage, debug, preview, and update if all the content is on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple to do in jQuery:

```
$("#yourDivsId").load("/UrlOfYourIntendedMarkupDelivery?anyarguments=true");
```